# Adicionar cor a texto em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Olá, estou com um probleminha, preciso adicionar uma cor a um texto que é adicionado dentro de um textarea através de um botão.

Já tentei utilizar x.style.color="red'"... Porém não funcionou, se alguém tiver uma solução por favor me apresente.

Segue o código:

```
<body>
<textarea name="texto" id="texto">
</textarea>

<button class="button button2" type="button1">Texto</button>

<script>
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var button1 = document.querySelector('button');
var assinatura1 = 'TEXTO COLORIDO'
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    textarea.value += assinatura1;
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: O que seria `x` em `x.style.color="red'"`?

Comment: "X" seria a variável, já que o texto (TEXTO COLORIDO) é passado para o textarea através da variável assinatura1.

Comment: Vc quer alterar só o texto "TEXTO COLORIDO" e deixar os outros sem colorir?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, se possível, já que o texto "TEXTO COLORIDO" é inserido no textarea sem apagar o que já estava escrito.

Comment: Entendi, mas já tem pergunta abordando isso. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá pelo javascript você pode fazer dessa maneira:

// Muda a cor do fundo:

```
document.getElementById('texto').style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; // ou a cor que quiser

// Muda a cor do texto:
document.getElementById('texto').style.color = 'black';
```

Comment: Oi Renato, já havia tentando essa segunda opção que você sugeriu. Porém não consegui, esqueci de informar que o texto que deve ganhar cor é o "TEXTO COLORIDO", e que ele é atribuído a uma variável, no caso a variável "assinatura1", e da forma sugerida isso não funcionou... Teria outra forma?

Comment: você pode atribuir uma cor para todo o `textarea`, não para um texto apenas.

Comment: Para fazer isso você precisa de um elemento que permita inserir conteúdo `html`, como um `div` ou `span`

Comment: Olá @SulivanSantos, como o Ricardo disse, dentro do mesmo elemento não tem como, você precisa criar uma div e separar os elementos e ai sim você pode fazer da forma que te passei. Espero ter ajudado. Abraços